Cannot resolve method 'series' in 'HttpStatusCode'
I have this Spring Boot 2 code which I want to migrate to Spring Boot 3:
import org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpResponse;

ClientHttpResponse httpResponse.....;

if (httpResponse.getStatusCode().series() == HttpStatus.Series.SERVER_ERROR) {
      ......
}

I get error Cannot resolve method 'series' in 'HttpStatusCode'.
Do you know what is the proper way to migrate this code?

In Spring Boot 2 (and thus Spring Web 5.x.x), HttpStatus.series() method returns the HTTP status series of the status code. The HttpStatus.Series.SERVER_ERROR is a series representing all 5xx HTTP Status codes.
From the docs mentioned above for HttpStatus, you can also read that the method HttpStatus.is5xxServerError() gives true if the status code is in the HTTP series HttpStatus.Series.SERVER_ERROR.
That understood, using Spring Boot 3 (and thus Spring Web 6.x.x) we can achieve the same result by just checking the status code is a 5xx, using the method HttpStatusCode.is5xxServerError() which gives true if the status code is in the Server Error class (5xx), like this:
import org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpResponse;

ClientHttpResponse httpResponse.....;

if (httpResponse.getStatusCode().is5xxServerError()) {
      ......
}

